# Include CoffeeScript into another one

Tags: coffeescript, include

It is a noob question, but I am looking for a solution, to include one coffeescript into another one, like in SASS or Pug(former Jade).

Like in sass:

```
@import ../sass/vars.sass
```

or in jade

```
include ../jade/footer.jade
```

I cannot find something like this in CoffeeScript. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Coffeescript is just a semi-language that is being translated into JS later on anyways, it does not allow modularization by itself. To build your app module-way, i prefer to use RequireJS, it works fine with CS.
http://requirejs.org/

Comment: I am a beginner, I only wanted to make it easier to edit on my computer by separating different modules into different files. I have a hierarchy I can use in both SASS and Jade, and it would have been great to use it with CoffeeScript too. But thanks. :)